# How to write a connection string to access Visual Studio 2017 Embed SQL Server

Tags: connection-string

I've been trying to access the database I created using SQL Server Explorer on Visual Studio 2017, like the image below:

[image]

I've been searching how to create a connection string to store on web.config, I just wasn't able to built one that access this database.

The connection I do have now is:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="databaseXXX" connectionString="Server=np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#0FB2D72B\tsql\query;Database=databaseXXX;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Already try the one below:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="databaseXXX" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=databaseXXX;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

But I can't find a way to make this connections strings works with the code below:

```cs
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/despachanteEBHandler");
        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
        if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
        {
            connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["databaseXXX"];
            _connectionString = connString.ConnectionString;
            _databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStrig);
            _databaseConnection.Open();
            _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(String.Empty, _databaseConnection);
        }
```

I know that there's a lot of similar questions, and a lot of answers (I looked on many before came here), but I should be missing something small or being to stupid.

I appreciate any help you people can provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

you can also look at this website it may help

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: It didn't worked.

<add name="despachanteEB" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=despachanteEB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: @try with user id and password first, try to access it using the management studio as well

Comment: I don't have the user/password this SQL Server came with VS2017, I never configured any user/password.

But the site you gave me did the trick, this one worked.

Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=True

Thanks!!!